# How to make new commands with alternative command definitions? i.e. NOT alternative arguments

Tags: macros

I want something like this:

```
\newcommand{\MyCommand}{default definition}{definition}
```

The context for wanting this is as follows:
I  am making automated reports for different customers, and am defining all sorts of customer-specific text variables when making the report. So these text variables should be defined in my latex template files, for instance:

```
\newcommand{\CustomerName}{LackingCustomerName}{}%
```

should be compiled to " ...LackingCustmerName...." in the report

while

```
\newcommand{\CustomerName}{LackingCustomerName}{Coca Cole Inc.}%
```

should be compiled to " ...Coca Cola Inc...." in the report.

By including a default definitions on the form "Lacking...Name" it can easily be seen in the compiled text which of the text variables that has yet to be defined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define a generic interface

```
\newcommand{\newcustomer}[2]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    % arg #2 is empty
    \newcommand{#1}{No value for \texttt{\string#1} has been defined}%
  \else
    \newcommand{#1}{#2}%
  \fi}
```

Then you can do

```
\newcustomer{\CustomerNameOne}{}
\newcustomer{\CustomerNameTwo}{ACME Inc.}
```

Change the "No value..." to what you prefer.

In order to disregard spaces in `\newcustomer{\Xyz}{ }` you have to "zap spaces". The easiest way, since your argument will only produce text is to measure the space it occupies:

```
\newcommand{\newcustomer}[2]{%
  \sbox0{\ignorespaces#2\unskip}%
  \ifdim\wd0=0pt
    % arg #2 is empty or only spaces
    \newcommand{#1}{No value for \texttt{\string#1} has been defined}%
  \else
    \newcommand{#1}{#2}%
  \fi}
```

For getting only `CustomerNameOne` (without the backslash), you can say

```
\newcommand{\newcustomer}[2]{%
  \sbox0{\ignorespaces#2\unskip}%
  \ifdim\wd0=0pt
    % arg #2 is empty or only spaces
    \newcommand{#1}{No value for \getname{#1} has been defined}%
  \else
    \newcommand{#1}{#2}%
  \fi}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\getname[1]{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks a lOt! That works fine. How can I make the code dissregard any open space in the definition of \CustomerNameOne`? That is, if I by a misstake write: \newcustomer{\CustomerNameOne}{ }, then the open space in the last pair of curly braces will be used as the name of the customer. How to prevent that?

Comment: Another question regarding your code "..{\string#1}...", where #1 is "`\CustomerNameOne". Can I somehow change this code in such a way that only "CustomerNameOne" will be used, i.e. only element 2...n of the string is used? How do I do that? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Thanks again :) However, I get an errormessage when using your code for removing empty spaces:  
"...! Incomplete \ifdim; all text was ignored after line 18.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.188 \input{../UserVariables.tex}
                                  
?"  Is there any code lacking in your solution?

Comment: @EspenDonali Are you using the babel module for Turkish? That should be the reason. But the problem doesn't show if the code is *before* `\begin{document}` as such code always should.

Comment: Hi egreg. Thanks som much for your help! Your second solution for removing "\" works fine ! However, when including code to delete open spaces I still get the afore mentioned error message. I am using Babel only for englis. And I have put the code in before the \begin{document}

By the way, do you have a good learning source (book or websidt) for better understanding the code you made for me? I mean, where can I read about the functions \sbox, \ignorespace, \unskip,\relax, \detokenize, \expandafter, \string and how they can be combined?

Comment: @EspenDonali For the error I really can't help without a minimal example. The `\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` and `\sbox0{...}` tricks are explained elsewhere on this site.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a value as default and then redefine it if required:

```
\newcommand{\CustomerName}{LackingCustomerName}

% ...
\renewcommand{\CustomerName}{Coca Cole Inc.}
```

However, the normal way this is done for variables like this (compare `\title`, `\author` etc.) is to use internal macros and let `\CustomerName` define it:

```
\newcommand{\CustomerName}[1]{\def\@CustomerName{#1}}
% Or maybe:
% \newcommand{\CustomerName}[1]{\def\theCustomerName{#1}}
\CustomerName{LackingCustomerName}%  default value

% ...
\CustomerName{Coca Cola Inc}
```

Then to typeset the customer name use:

```
Customer: \@CustomerName     % if only used internally in your package/class
% or
Customer: \theCustomerName   % if also used directly in the document
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I didn't succeed in making your code work for some reason. Should all the code you have written in the second block of code be together in the preamble??


Further, I want the default-value to be part of the definition of the \CustomerName code. Can that be accomplished?

Comment: @EspenDonali: Any code containing macros with an `@` need to be either in a package or class file or be placed inside `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`.

Answer (score 1):

For just the problem you described, you could leave you normal definitions like they are, but overwrite them later with `\renewcommand`. You would have e.g. a

```
\newcommand{\CustomerName}{LackingCustomerName}
```

in your preamble (maybe in a different file). In your report you could then 'overwrite' the variable using e.g.

```
\renewcommand{\CustomerName}{Coca Cola Inc.}
```

I would do it in a different way though: I would just not define a 'default' `\CustomerName`... This way the compiler would scream at you for forgetting to set a variable.

What you could also do is creating all commands you need, but setting them to commands like:

```
\PackageError{Customer Template}{forgot to redefine \CustomerName}{Please overwrite \\CustomerName by using \renewcommand}
\PackageWarning{Customer Template}{forgot to redefine \\CustomerName, boilerplate still in the file}
\PackageInfo{Customer Template}{forgot to redefine \\CustomerName, boilerplate still in the file}
```

This might greately reduce the risk of forgetting to redefine on of your commands and end up with a report that is sent to someone called 'LackingCustomerName'

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\CustomerName}{\PackageError{mypack}{blub}{blub}}
\renewcommand{\CustomerName}{Coca Cola Inc.}

\begin{document}
\CustomerName
\end{document}
```